# State updating without setState

Tags: reactjs

I learned that I need to take a copy of my state before updating but I noticed that even before I call setState() the state is updated:

```
let drags = {...this.state.drags};

// Current item
drags[key].offsetMove = null;

// State already updated?
this.setState({drags});
```

Does the ...spread operator still work by reference?

Comment: Why do you think the state is already updated?

Comment: it updates without this.setState({drags});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{...this.state.drags}` makes a **shallow** copy of the object. If any values inside that object are objects, they will be referenced, not copied.

`drags[key].offsetMove = null;` is modifying the existing object in `drags[key]`, which is referenced by the old state and your new shallow copy of state. If you want to fully avoid mutations, build a new object at that specific key.

```
var drags = {
    ...this.state.drags,
    [key]: {
        ...this.state.drags[key],
        offsetMove: null
    }
}
```

For the record, your code is completely fine for React. This is also completely fine:

```
const { drags } = this.state;
drags[ key ].offsetMove = null;
this.setState({ drags });
```

Your component will still update just fine. However, for libraries like redux, any time you change a property of an object, redux expects a new object, which the first code block in the example would produce. As a personal choice, I always use something like the first style, and almost never mutate objects. The most insidious bugs I've found in my applications happen because someone mutated an object and I wasn't expecting it. Making a new copy of an object with a changed key ensures anyone who has a reference to the old object won't have the rug pulled out from under them.

Comment: performance isn't a concern for things like this. Using lodash / immutableJS are more personal and opinion choices. Using es6, especially with the object spread operator, I have found no need for lodash/underscore/immutable etc.